# Find covariance if given mean and variance

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, covariance-matrix

I have a signal x that I want to classify in one of the classes A and B in which the means are

```
Ma=[0.5,0.6] and Mb=[2,2]
```

and with variances

```
Va=1 and Vb=2.
```

And to classify the signal I have to use the Mahalanobis distance which  requires the covariance S that those classes share and have in common. Can I find it if there is only given the mean and variance between those classes?

P.S I know this looks like a homework exercise but I have been looking everywhere and I could not find anything

Comment: The two subclauses of your 'P.S.' are not logically connected. Is this a homework exercise? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Thanks you for adding the tag. What would you do if you had the full covariance matrices?

Comment: The mahalanobis distance formula requires the covariance matrice to be able to calculate the distances between the signal x to the classes A and B

Comment: Do you actually have the data? I thought you didn't. If you don't, how would you calculate this for a given x?

Comment: I do have the data for x[1.1,1.5] but from the sources I have get you can't calculate the covariance with one point only...Or  maybe I have got it wrong...

Comment: So you have data for only a single point? How did you calculate the means & variances?

Comment: They were given

Comment: And only 1 datum was given? So how would you classify this point if you had the full covariance matrices?

Comment: With the Mahalanobis distance between the signal x to the classes A and B

Comment: & then what? Be as specific & concrete as possible. It may help you to make up a couple of covariance matrices & work through the problem.

Comment: The formula goes like this d(A,x)=sqroot[(x-A)^T*S^-1(x-A)]. I already have the (x-A)^T and (x-A) but working to find the covariance S between class A and B I have S=[s11,s12,s21,s22]=[1,s12,21,2]. Which leaves me to find the s12 and s21 variables on the covariance which I can't understand how I am going to do that

Comment: What will you do when you have d(A,x)? Try making up some numbers for s12 & s21, & trying it.  Also, try plotting the means, w/ error bars for the SDs, & the x-point.

Comment: Depending on the results between d(A,x) and d(B,x) the signal x will  be classified to the class with the minimum distance. I am not sure if I can make  up numbers for s12 & s21

Comment: Sure you can--it's just an exercise. Think about the maximum & minimum possible values (remember that s12=s21) & try w/ both. What do you find?

Comment: I know that  I'm answering after 2  days and I apologize for the delay. I  was reading that the covariance matrix  measures the distance  between i-th and j-th elements, so  if the s11 and s22 is the variance of the classes A and B could it s12 and s21 be the distance between A-B? So s12=s21=(Ma1-Mb1)*(Ma2-Mb2)??

Comment: That's OK. Take a step back. What are the minimum & maximum possible values for s12? Consider the min & max for a correlation matrix. You can convert from a correlation to a covariance by multiplying by the variances.

Comment: Because the classes are independent the maximum and minimum correlation isnt gonna be 0? Sorry but I am so lost, this has been troubling me for days

Comment: You have 2 classes of objects that exist w/i a 2D space (x1, x2). The question is how the data covary w/i that space. Ie, the correlation is b/t x1 & x2. If you know that x1 & x2 are independent (is that part of the problem statement, or background info you are supposed to assume?), then you know the correlation & you can calculate the covariance from there.

Comment: The problem states that the two classes have  a common covariance matrix that was produced by independent characteristics with variances Va=1 and Vb=2.

Comment: The "characteristics" are what I called "x1 & x2". If you know they are independent, you know the correlation & from that the covariance.

Comment: So if the classes are independent then that means that  the cov(A,B)=0? since ρ(Α,Β)=0

Comment: It stands to reason. Can you solve it from here?

Comment: If we got the cov(A,B) right then I think I can solve it .Anyway thank you so much  for your time that you spent helping me .

Comment: OK. I'll make an official answer in a bit. GL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two classes of objects that exist within a two dimensional space defined by two characteristics $(x_1, x_2)$. The issue here is how the data covary within that space. That is, there is some value for the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$. If you know that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent, then you know the correlation that corresponds to independence.  From there, you can calculate the covariance using the definition of correlation:
$$
{\rm Cor}(x_1, x_2) = \frac{{\rm Cov(x_1, x_2)}}{{\rm Var(x_1)}{\rm Var(x_2)}}
$$
Remember that a correlation matrix is symmetrical.  That is, $s_{12}=s_{21}$.  With that last piece, you should be able to construct the correlation matrix and solve the problem.

Comment: But what do you do if you don't have the correlation? I mean the original question, you have only mean and variance.

Comment: @xkcd, if you know x1 & X2 are independent, you can infer the correlation from that. If you didn't know whether they were independent, you could use background knowledge to impute a distribution of possible correlations (like a prior) & integrate over that.