# MLE in R for exponential distribution

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to find the MLE based on this data set. However, I am always getting errors. Here is the code:

```
x       <- c(1.636, 0.374, 0.534, 3.015, 0.932, 0.179)
nloglik <- function(x, theta){ sum(-dexp(x=x, rate=theta, log=T)) }
optimize(f=nloglik, x=x, interval=c(0,5))$par
```

Comment: What do you mean the MLE of a data set?  You can have MLEs of parameters, and if you have an exponential distribution it is not hard to obtain the MLE for the mean parameter without software.

Comment: thx for the reply. for my knowledge mle for exp(lamda) is just sample mean, but my homework required to do it by R..so

Comment: In that case just enter `mean(c(1.636, 0.374, 0.534, 3.015, 0.932, 0.179))`.  There's no need to maximize the likelihood numerically once you have a closed form analytical solution.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the `$par` that is messing up the code.  Try this instead:

```
x<- c(1.636, 0.374, 0.534, 3.015, 0.932, 0.179)

nloglik<- function(x,theta) sum(-dexp(x=x,rate=theta,log=T))

optimize(f=nloglik,x=x,interval = c(0,5))$minimum
```

and so the minimum value returned by the optimize function corresponds to the value of the MLE. You can check this by recalling the fact that the MLE for an exponential distribution is:

$$\hat\lambda=\frac{1}{\bar x}$$
where $\bar x= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Calculating that in `R` gives the following:

```
> 1/mean(x)
[1] 0.8995502
```

which is roughly the same as using the optimization approach:

```
> optimize(f=nloglik,x=x,interval = c(0,5))$minimum
[1] 0.8995525
```

Comment: thx so much, tried to do it for three days...

Comment: @QuinieQiao no problem.

Comment: Please don't provide complete answers for people's homework, but hints only. Our policy is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung I wasn't aware when I wrote the answer that it was a homework questions.  If we provide hints should they be posted as an answer or as a comment?

Comment: You can do either, at your discretion. I usually provide hints in a long back & forth in comments to the Q, & then summarize them into an answer after they got it themselves. Sometimes I start an answer with a prompt & have the comment conversation below the answer. It just depends. Glen_b is the king of self-study; for an example of where I've done this, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/190535/7290).

Comment: @gung ok, just wanted to double check so that I don't get penalized or rather down voted for providing a solution that isn't a solution in its entirety.

Comment: You shouldn't.  You can also clearly state at the beginning of your answer that you are just giving them hints / partial information to nudge them along.